# Clear bit if another is set

Tags: c++, optimization, bit-manipulation

Is there's a similar to:
`if((bitmap & BIT_WATER) && (bitmap & BIT_FIRE)) bitmap &= ~BIT_FIRE`
or
`if(bitmap & BIT_WATER) bitmap &= ~BIT_FIRE`

In a single statement using only bitwise operations, removing the need of a comparation (if)?

I totally mean that if two flag, each completly opposite to the other, are set clear one of them.

Comment: `bitmap &= ~(bit_fire * static_cast<bool>(bitmap & bit_water));`, but it uses multiplication...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promoting my comment to an answer. Note, it uses multiplication, but maybe it will be still useful to you ([code on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/RZP7JG)):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
 int long unsigned bitmap_with_water = 0xF300003F;
 int long unsigned bitmap_without_water = 0xF300000F;
 int long unsigned bit_fire = 0x03000000;
 int long unsigned bit_water = 0x00000030;

 bitmap_with_water &= ~(bit_fire * static_cast<bool>(bitmap_with_water & bit_water));
 bitmap_without_water &= ~(bit_fire * static_cast<bool>(bitmap_without_water & bit_water));

 std::cout << (void*)(bitmap_with_water) << "\t" << (void*)(bitmap_without_water) << std::endl;

 return (0);
}
```

Program output:

```
0xf000003f  0xf300000f
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the `bitmap & BIT_FIRE` in the first case, since `bitmap &= ~BIT_FIRE;` will do nothing to the `bitmap` if `BIT_FIRE` is not set.

There is no "set bit X if bit Y is set" in an arbitrary way.

Of course, if you KNOW that, say, `BIT_FIRE` is one bit higher than `BIT_WATER`, you could do `bitmap &= ~(BIT_WATER << 1)`, which will clear the "one bit higher than `BIT_WATER`".

Comment: Sorry, my bad, edited the question with the corrected code, it was supposed to be ~BIT_FIRE not ~BIT_WATER.

Comment: @LINK2012: Ok, edited to reflect your know question. The short answer is still "there is no general/simple way to achieve this".

Comment: Could you also do `bitmap &= ~((bitmap & BIT_WATER) * (BIT_FIRE/BIT_WATER))` if you know BIT_FIRE > BIT_WATER ?

Comment: @MikeDunlavey And if `BIT_FIRE/BIT_WATER == 432`, for example?

Comment: @Petr: I assume these bits are in an integer word, so they are powers of 2, and dividing one by the other will be a power of 2, which when you multiply becomes a shift.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey Yes, I just don't think we can assume that `BIT_FIRE` is actually just a single bit set to `1`. It can be few bits set to `1`.

Comment: @Petr: I suppose, but the OP did call them "bit" :)

Answer (score 2):

Probably premature optimization, but you could do

```
bitmap &= ~((bitmap & BIT_WATER) * (BIT_FIRE/BIT_WATER)) & ~((bitmap & BIT_WATER) * (BIT_WATER/BIT_FIRE))
```

as long as BIT_FIRE and BIT_WATER are single bits (powers of 2).  You probably also want bitmap to be unsigned to insure that the compiler can easily optimize this down to a single shift, two bitwise ands, and a complement.

Of course, a good compiler would optimize your original code down to the same 4 instructions with no branch.

**edit**

Of course, I realized the above is incorrect -- only works if BIT_FIRE > BIT_WATER.

So just stick with the original if and let the compiler optimize it...

Comment: + OK, you can have my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to write a general purpose `clear_if_set(int test, int clear, int bitmap)` then this answer is useless.

If this is a specialized function and you know the shift distance from fire to water:

```
int water = bitmap & BIT_WATER;
int shifted = water << WATER_TO_FIRE_LSHIFT; // for example
bitmap &= ~shifted;
```

One-liner:

```
bitmap &= ~((bitmap & BIT_WATER) << WATER_TO_FIRE_LSHIFT);
```

Answer (score 1):

If using bit numbers instead of pre-shifted bit masks is acceptable:

```
bitmap &= ~(((bitmap >> SHIFT_WATER) & 1) << SHIFT_FIRE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming BIT_WATER and BIT_FIRE are not the same bit then

the truth table for

```
if(bitmap & BIT_WATER) bitmap &= ~BIT_FIRE
```

is (BIT_WATER, old BIT_FIRE, new BIT_FIRE)

```
0 0   0
0 1   1
1 0   0
1 1   0
```

So from a bit perspective that is

```
BIT_FIRE = (~BIT_WATER)&BIT_FIRE;

1 0   0
1 1   1
0 0   0
0 1   0
```

Since I dont know the gap between your two bits then something like this which is excessive.

```
newbit = ((~(bitmap>>BIT_WATER_BIT))&(bitmap>>BIT_FIRE_BIT))&1;
bitmap&=~BIT_FIRE;
bitmap|=newbit<<BIT_FIRE_BIT;
```

Assuming I didnt make a typo...Also which I assume can be simplified if you take advantage of the specific bit numbers and not do something generic (shift BIT_WATER bit over to land on BIT_FIRE rather than shift everything right then left again.  May not make it simpler though.

if bit water bit is 7 and bit fire bit is 3

```
bitmap = (((~(bitmap>>4))>>4)&(1<<3))&bitmap;
```

Or maybe this

```
bitmap = (((bitmap&(~BIT_WATER))^BIT_WATER)>>4)&bitmap;
```

where >>4 is the direction and delta between BIT_WATER and BIT_FIRE.  fill in the proper delta.